# I can't get new value from autocomplete react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using autocomplete of material UI in my react app, I want to get the value when I change the item but I am getting undefined.

Here is my code

```
<Controller
                name="partnerId"
                control={control}
                defaultValue={[]}
                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                    <Autocomplete
                        id="filter-demo"
                        className="mt-8 mb-16"
                        defaultValue={personObj}
                        value={value}
                        onChange={(newValue) => {
                            console.log('value...', newValue)
                            onChange(newValue);
                        }}
                        variant="outlined"
                        options={partners}
                        getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
                        filterOptions={filterOptions}
                        renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} label="Partners" variant="outlined" />}
                    />
                )}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try onchange as

```
onChange={(event,newValue) => {
                           console.log('value...', newValue)
                           onChange(newValue);
                       }}
```